# Optimizing String manupulation code

Tags: java, string

I am trying to all possible child domains from a given host. I have written following code. It works but my only worry is performance.

Is it required to optimize this code further:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DemoExtractHostArray {
    public static  String[] createHostArray(String host) {
        String[] stringArr = host.split("\\.");
        String[] hostArray = new String[stringArr.length];
        int hostIndex = 0;

        for(int index = stringArr.length-1; index>=0;index--){
            if(hostIndex==0){ 
                hostArray[hostIndex] = stringArr[index];
            }
            else{
                hostArray[hostIndex] = stringArr[index]+"."+hostArray[hostIndex-1];
            }
            hostIndex++;
        }
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(hostArray));
        return hostArray;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        for(String s: createHostArray("a.b.c.d.e.f")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
a.b.c.d.e.f
b.c.d.e.f
c.d.e.f
d.e.f
e.f
f
```

Comment: Well, does it perform badly? Did you profile your application and find out that this is a hotspot?

Comment: Optimization isn't "required" unless this is going to be used in a performance-critical loops somewhere.

Comment: Hint: never try to guess performance problems, it's a very inefficient way of finding them.

Comment: This code will get called millions of times. Based on the traffic.

Comment: If performance is really that much of an issue, you could always declare your methods as "native" and implement them using the Java Native Interface.

Comment: @75inchpianist - I saw your code. Compared to looping version, will it not create additional String arrays which will be local to each method call in recursion ? Looping version creates String array only once, if we include code suggested by dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potential improvement to your code is removing this call:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(hostArray));
```

Since you are creating the `hostArray` and then reversing it, you might as well change the loop to create the array in reverse order right away, so as to no longer requiring an explicit reversal:

```
// hostIndex is no longer required - remove the line below:
// int hostIndex = 0;
for(int index = stringArr.length-1 ; index>=0 ; index--){
    if(index == stringArr.length-1) {
        hostArray[index] = stringArr[index];
    }
    else{
        hostArray[index] = stringArr[index]+"."+hostArray[index+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also create `StringBuilder[]` instead of `String[]`. Your source code in `if` statement could look like this: `hostArray[index].append(....);` Think about it.

Comment: @MichałZiober This will not improve much, because each concatenation is done only once, and all the intermediate results are kept.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use recusion. This implementation does not require the reversal of the array and, in my opinion, may be easier to follow.

http://ideone.com/MnMZOL

```
package com.poachit.utility.web;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DemoExtractHostArray {
     public static void createHostArray(String[] root, String[] result, int index) {

        String host="";
        int i = index;
        if (index == root.length) {
            return;
        }
        for ( ; i < root.length-1; i++) {           
            host += root[i] + ".";
        }

        if (i < root.length) {
            host += root[i];
        }

        result[index] = host;
        createHostArray(root, result, ++index);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String host = "a.b.c.d.e.f";

        String [] tokens = host.split("\\.");

        String [] result = new String[tokens.length];

      createHostArray(tokens, result, 0);

      for (String s : result) {
        System.out.println(s);
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a tail-call. Recursion is unnecessary and overly expensive for this task; you can simply loop, incrementing index each time through the loop until `index==root.length`. Even simpler and easier to read, as well as more performant.

Comment: unless he is doing hundreds of thousands of hosts performance really is negligible. You won't notice execution time hits from adding a few frames on the stack through recursion. this really is a matter of preference.

Comment: Absolutely agree. But the question as posed was performance. And loop _is_ clearer than tailcall for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the code like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static  String[] createHostArray(String host) {
        String[] stringArr = host.split("\\.");
        String[] hostArray = new String[stringArr.length];
        int hostIndex = 0;

        for(int index = stringArr.length-1; index>=0;index--){
            if(hostIndex==0){ 
                hostArray[hostIndex] = stringArr[index];
            }
            else{
                hostArray[hostIndex] = stringArr[index]+"."+hostArray[hostIndex-1];
            }
            hostIndex++;
        }
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(hostArray));
        return hostArray;
    }

    public static  String[] betterCreateHostArray(String host) {
        List<String> hostList = new ArrayList<String>();
        do {
            if(!host.contains(".")) {
                hostList.add(host);
                break;
            } else {
                hostList.add(host);
                host = host.substring(host.indexOf('.')+1);
            }
        } while(host.length() > 0);

        return hostList.toArray(new String[hostList.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] array = createHostArray("a.b.c.d.e.f");
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeByFirstApproach = endTime - startTime;

        for(String s: array){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("=====");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        array = betterCreateHostArray("a.b.c.d.e.f");
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeBySecondApproach = endTime - startTime;
        for(String s: array){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Time taken by first approach=[%d] nano seconds and\n"
                + "Time taken by second approach=[%d] nano seconds", timeByFirstApproach,timeBySecondApproach));
    }
}
```

and here the performance result

a.b.c.d.e.f
b.c.d.e.f
c.d.e.f
d.e.f
e.f
f
=====
a.b.c.d.e.f
b.c.d.e.f
c.d.e.f
d.e.f
e.f
f
Time taken by first approach=[1625572] nano seconds and
Time taken by second approach=[308289] nano seconds

Second approach is more than 5 times faster than the approach you are following.